# Assign a volume pedal to a DSP on a Psr keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, organ, keyboard-pedals

I have a yamaha Psr-2100, and a volume pedal (yamaha fc7). I was hoping I could assign my pedal to affect a certain parameter of an effect that is applied on a voice, for example distortion or vibrato. This would be very useful for like Organ playing.

I found a way to have a main voice and a layer, and only applying the volume pedal to the layer. The layer would then be a copy of the main voice, only with the added effect (distortion enabled). This does give a bit of what I was hoping for, however since now everytime I 'enable distortion' I get a big volume boost, which isn't really desirable.

Anyone knows how to assign the pedal to an effect/dsp, or otherwise an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

So the pedal is working ok, then.  It's just a matter of you figuring out the sound module part of your keyboard?  Not having that keyboard, I'd say it's time to dig through the manual and pray :)  Sorry, not much of an answer, I know...  google the manufacturer's website for the manual in .pdf form if you lost it.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would say is, you can't.   Unless you mean to ask "how can I turn DSP on and off?".
I that case, hit the shortcut button, then the paddle, then scroll with the wheel and look for an option "dsp on/off".
If you don't see it, then you probably can't do that.
Also, there is a similar trick that may help: in the voice settings of the instrument (which you should be able to access from the voice folder with a up arrow) you should find two options called "amplitude" and "filter" (to be sure, find amplitude. Whatever is right next to it should be the correct one).
Set one to max (127) and the other one to min (0).
You'll know if you do the wrong combination (the are only two!) because it will probably go mute on you.